# Keep the existing columns and convert the row to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

There are three columns in a dataFrame Ticker, Attribute, and Value.

[The original dataFrame can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNSkc.png)

I want to set the Attribute values as a column which can easily be done by setting it as an index and then taking the transpose but the problem is that I want to keep the Ticker as a column when I take the transpose it become the row.
[When I take Attribute as an index and take its transpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPfAL.png)

When I set both as an index and then take transpose it looks something like this which I don't want
[When both the Attribute and Ticker taken as index and transposed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaCeG.png)

What I want is this
[The required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X957D.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index= 'Ticker', columns='Attribute', values = 'Value')
```

Comment: The values column isn't numeric when I try, it throws an error
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Doesn't work for me either, not sure why this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Ticker': list('AAAAABBBB'),
    'Key': list('112341234'),
    'Value':list('ZQWERQWER')
})
```

To deal with duplicates group by your index and key and aggregate your groups in any way you like. Here I use first, you could also accumulate entire groups using `list`, for example:

```py
df = df.groupby(['Ticker', 'Key'])['Value'].first().reset_index()
```

Then, finally, pivot the table:

```py
df = df.pivot(index='Ticker', columns='Key', values='Value').reset_index()
```

Comment: Ticker contains duplicates pivot doesn't allow duplicates so when i try to drop duplicates i left with single columns Market Cap

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @AdnanKhan - edited the answer and added some code that deals with duplicates. Let me know if anything else needs clarifying.

Comment: @rudolfovic Thanks I was trying to concatenate the two dataframes so I applied the pivot separately on both the dataframes and joined after pivoting it worked for me